# Margin+padding doesn't compensate on Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, hover, margin, padding

Speaking of browsers differences, it looks that Chrome handles margin+padding a bit differently than others.

Take this example, that aims to display a expanded background through an negative margin while preserving text position through a padding compensation:

```
a:hover {
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 0.3em;
  margin: -0.3em;
}
```

It works fine as long as your `display` enforce *block* display (but can imply horizontal move, if you use `inline-block` for example), but using `inline` will strangely "shrink" the link by 1 px (from the right or the left, depending on text width and container width), as if hovered inline links were smaller than non-hovered ones (of course, this does not happen without such styling).

None of those moves occur on Firefox or Safari.
See [demonstration of issue here](http://jsfiddle.net/Javarome/oof5zjdw/11/).

Can someone explain this? Is it a bug specific to Chrome or a Chrome feature (I saw there is `-webkit-margin-after` and `-webkit-margin-before` for example)? At worse a workaround would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Looks like mainly a rounding issue – up the `.3` in your example to `.5`, and the effect is gone … Whether there’s a “workaround”, depends in the complexity of the issue and what you want to actually achieve here … for you simple example, you could simply set the padding and negative margin for the links to begin with, and only change the background on hover.

Comment: Just use pixels instead of em in your padding/margin styles and your problem is solved

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with the fact that you are using `em` instead of a concrete rule such as `px`. You can see this here:

http://jsfiddle.net/oof5zjdw/10/

The `em` measurement is dynamic and chrome appears to calculate the measurement slightly different for padding vs margin

Answer (score 1):

I think this is more related to the half pixel thing in the CSS. If found it's interesting too. We use the same demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/oof5zjdw/12/

So pay attention on this style `border-right: .5px solid red;`

Firefox will display it (either 1px or nearly to 1px, couldn't really tell), but Safari/Chrome won't show it at all.